# What's the most idiomatic way to pass data between embedded struct?

Tags: go, design-patterns

I have two structs

```
//Pseudo code
type task struct {}
type tasks struct []{
     t task 
}
```

I want to run one task and after it finished to pass information to tasks:  For example, after `task1` and `task2` finished, notify `tasks` , and then run `task3`. So this one `task.finished()` have to notify `tasks.` and `tasks` have to make sure both `task1` and `task2` have finished then to trigger task3.

```
 //Pseudo code    
 task1.start() and task2.start() at the same time

 if  task1.finished() && task2.finished():
     task3.run()
```

What's the most idiomatic way to pass data between embedded structs?

I understand such logic should be proceed in `tasks` but how do `task1` and `task2` tell `tasks` they are finished?

Should I introduce a new struct that stores the information needed for exchange called "taskManager"?

Comment: There are no sub- or parent structs in Go, so there is no way, idiomatic or otherwise, to handle this relationship. The closest there is are embedded structs, and there is no way to handle this relationship directly (that would violate the concept of embedding). But that's not what you have, anyway.

Comment: Can you please add some more context; currently something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/SbYvL7C-VPO) would seem to meet your requirements (doing away with ```tasks.runNextTask()```) but I doubt its what you are looking for. Perhaps mock up something that does what you need (or meets most of your goals) and then ask for improvements/better implementations?

Comment: In your case, what you probably need is a method on `tasks` that controls each `task`.

Comment: @Brits I have updated the example. Does it make sense?

Comment: Your code makes sense but doesn't explain why you can't just iterate through the tasks as the code I [linked to in my last comment](https://play.golang.org/p/SbYvL7C-VPO) does. Perhaps take that code as a starting point and explain why it does not meet your needs?

Comment: I have read the code. My assumption is I have to start task1 and task2 at the same time, but they would finish at different time. I think that's what missing.

Comment: @Flimzy Note that they are `Pseudo code`

Comment: But as has been mentioned by at least two of us now, the way to handle this is from `tasks`.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, I agree. But I am not sure what's the best way to notify `tasks` that task1 and task2 have finished.

Comment: The same way any other function indicates that it's done. Possibilities include: Not returning until it's done, returning a channel that is closed when it's done, sending a value on a channel when it's done, updating some shared state when it's done, etc, etc

Comment: "My assumption is I have to start task1 and task2 at the same time" - this sounds like you don't fully understand  the requirements yourself? Currently you have not provided enough information for us to provide an answer (there are a multitude of questions such as: how many tasks should be running simultaneously; are they standalone or does the output from one feed into the others, what happens when no tasks are running, are new tasks added while the system is running...).

Comment: For completeness here is an example that runs [two tasks simultaneously](https://play.golang.org/p/cJNnfvomExA).

Answer (score 1):

```
type tasks []*task

type task struct {
    Data       int
    onComplete chan struct{}
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

// each task will in one goroutine
// pointer receiver
func (t *task) Run() {
    defer wg.Done()

    sleepTime := time.Second * time.Duration(t.Data)

    fmt.Println("Task:", t.Data, "sleeping for", sleepTime)
    time.Sleep(sleepTime)

    fmt.Println("Task:", t.Data, "done")

    // Once work is done, Inform, if we have to
    if t.onComplete != nil {
        t.onComplete <- struct{}{}
    }
}

// Run given tasks
func Run(ts tasks) {
    wg.Add(len(ts))

    for _, t := range ts {
        // run each task in seperate goroutines
        go t.Run()
    }
}

func (ts tasks) OnComplete(pending tasks) {
    tempChan := make(chan struct{})

    // all tasks should inform to `tempChan`,
    // once done
    for _, t := range ts {
        t.onComplete = tempChan
    }

    tasksNum := len(ts)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        // once we receive enough signals
        // i.e., once all `ts` tasks are done run pending tasks
        for range tempChan {
            tasksNum--
            if tasksNum == 0 {
                Run(pending)
                close(tempChan)
            }
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
}

func main() {

    // define tasks
    mainTasks := tasks{
        {Data: 1},
        {Data: 2},
    }

    // tasks which need to run once certain tasks were done
    pendingTasks := tasks{
        {Data: 3},
    }

    // Inform to run pending tasks once mainTasks are done
    mainTasks.OnComplete(pendingTasks)

    // start runing your main tasks
    Run(mainTasks)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

[Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/z38TZqbgT1N)

In-fact you can keep on chaining the work, were `pendingTasks.OnComplete(someMoreTasks)`

Then run `mainTasks`, once done will run `PendingTasks`, once done will run `someMoreTasks`.

Other kind of complex relations are possible as well.